# Zipping a folder

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am trying to use

```
TZipFile.ZipDirectoryContents()
```

Like so:

```
TZipFile.ZipDirectoryContents('Test.PCF', WorkingDir);
```

If I am reading this right, it should save the contents of folder "workingdir" into a file named Test.pcf.

Now when I do this I get error::

```
Raised exception class EFOpenError with message Cannot open file
...test.pcf. The process cannot access the file because its being used by another process."
```

Two things confuse me:

1. It says that it cannot open file. There is no test.pcf yet. I was hoping this would create it.
2. It says cannot access file. Is this because it's not created yet? Am I using this function wong? If so how would I create a zip file from a folder location?

Comment: Likewise, I am not familar with TZipFile but could it be that 'Test.PCF' is within the directory you are attempting to zip up?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tested your code and it failed in the same way as you reported.

I then created an empty zip file manually by running WinZip.

*Then* ran your code and it ran fine.

It appears that the zip file has to already exist for ZipDirectoryContents to work.

To create a zip file programatically:

```
  myZipFile := TZIpFile.Create;
  myZipFile.Open('c:\myfolder\newzipfile.zip', TZipMode.zmWrite);
  myZipFile.Close;
  myZipFile.Free;
```

This line will then work:

```
  TZipFile.ZipDirectoryContents('c:\myfolder\newzipfile.zip', WorkingDir);
```